# Perl script literally prints http headers instead of understanding them

Tags: html, perl

I couldn't think of better keywords to Google this issue, so I apologize if this is a duplicate.

Here is my `logout.pl` script that basically erases cookie:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;

my $q = new CGI;

print $q->header('text/html');

my $cookie = $q->cookie(
  -name    => 'CGISESSID',
  -value   => '',
  -expires => '-1d'
);

print $q->header(-cookie=>$cookie);
print $q->redirect('welcome.pl');

exit;
```

When I run this script in a browser, it prints the following:

```
Set-Cookie: CGISESSID=; path=/; expires=Mon, 17-Feb-2014 09:05:42 GMT Date: Tue, 18 Feb 2014 09:05:42 GMT Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 Status: 302 Found Location: welcome.pl
```

What I want, however, is for the browser to delete the cookie and redirect to `welcome.pl`.

Comment: @Prix This is printed: `Status: 302 Found Location: welcome.pl`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you `print $q->header`, that prints *all* the headers, including the blank line which signals the end of headers, making anything after it content.  You need to only `print $q->header` once, no more.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually one more problem you might not figure out on your own. The “clear” cookie you’re trying to send to expire the session must be sent with the redirect. The `-w` switch is not usually what you want, just the `use warnings` you have too. Also, redirect URLs RFC:MUST be absolute. "welcome.pl" will in most likelihood work but it’s not a good practice and I had relative URIs bite very badly in a modperl app once. So, amended–

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use URI;

my $q = CGI->new;

my $cookie = $q->cookie(
  -name    => 'CGISESSID',
  -value   => '',
  -expires => '-1d'
);

my $welcome = URI->new_abs("welcome.pl", $q->url);

print $q->redirect( -uri => $welcome,
                    -cookie => $cookie,
                    -status => 302 );

exit;
```

Comment: This cleared a lot of my subconscious 'best practice' doubts. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use $q->header only once in your script and that should be before using anything printable on page